# how to collect text data from a URL link with or without ".html" in the link?

Tags: python, html, url, beautifulsoup

I am trying to collect some text data from a URL like https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html.

I would like to get the following text data from the html

```
 1.1. Linear Models¶
 The following are a set of methods intended for regression in which the target value is 
 expected to be a linear combination of the features. In mathematical notation, if 
 is the predicted value.
```

My code:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
link = "https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html"
f = urllib.request.urlopen(link)
html = f.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
print(soup.prettify())
```

How to navigate into the embedded body of the html to get the above text data ?

Also, I need to do the similar things for some links without ".html", I use the same code but no anything of the text data is returned from the link.

I cannot see anything of the text data when I printed it out by

```
 print(soup.prettify())
```

The return status is

```
  200
```

What could be the reason ?

thanks

Comment: Can you share the URL of the link? It might be the data is loaded via JavaScript and beautifulsoup doesn't see it

Answer (score 0):

When creating a `BeautifulSoup` object, you have to specify the parser that you want to use. Apart from that, I also recommend you to use `requests` instead of `urllib`, but it is completely your wish. Here is how you extract the text that you want:

```
div = soup.find('div', class_ = "section") #Finds the div with class section

print(div.h1.text) #Prints the text within the first h1 tag within the div

print(div.p.text) #Prints the text within the first p tag within the div
```

Output:

```
1.1. Linear Models¶
The following are a set of methods intended for regression in which
the target value is expected to be a linear combination of the features.
In mathematical notation, if \(\hat{y}\) is the predicted
value.
```

Here is the full code:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
link = "https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html"
f = urllib.request.urlopen(link)
html = f.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html5lib')

div = soup.find('div', class_ = "section")

print(div.h1.text)

print(div.p.text)
```